# How to implement a good Android global object to pass data in real-time from background thread to activity in real-time without deadlock?

Tags: android, concurrency, real-time, deadlock, mutual-exclusion

@Jusit suggested I use a global object to pass data from a background thread to an activity and it worked. But now I am worried about deadlock and if there is a good way to avoid/prevent it. Also I am not sure my choice of String as a global object is such a good one. Here's an explanation what I have currently done.

Actually the global object is just a public static variable created in Blueterm.java as shown below:

```
public class BlueTerm extends Activity {
    // a global object I guess
    public static String strData = "";
    // a couple of booleans to control reads/writes
    public static boolean strWrite = false;
    public static boolean strRead = false;
    ...
}
```

So strData I suppose is my global object created and written to by a background thread as follows:

```
while (BlueSentry.strRead == true);
BlueSentry.strWrite = true;
BlueSentry.strData = BlueSentry.strData + Character.toString(printableB);
BlueSentry.strWrite = false;
```

My intention is for strRead to prevent strData from being over written while my plotting activity is reading it. strWrite prevents my plotting activity from reading strData while it is being written as follows:

```
while (BlueSentry.strWrite == true);
BlueSentry.strRead = true;
String strData = BlueSentry.strData;
BlueSentry.strData = "";
BlueSentry.strRead = false
```

You can see that strData gets reset to an empty string after the plotting activity is through reading it.

I have experienced a force close while my phone was not connected to debugging with the USB, so I am not sure what caused the force close. And it has not happened since.

Any suggestions for achieving concurrency here without deadlock? I have read about mutual-exclusion (semaphores, locks, mutex), but I am not sure which if any I should use. Also maybe my choice of String as a global object is a bad one, since I want real-time data transfer. That is I don't want the thread blocked waiting for the activity finish reading. And I don't want the activity blocked waiting for the background thread to finish writing. May I should get rid of String and implement/use a FIFO buffer instead, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Handler (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) as the communication technique if you are going from a background thread to an Activity. See https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html for a quick tutorial, but in short:

1. Create a Handler in your activity that accepts the value of `Character.toString(printableB)` in a Message.
2. Pass the Handler to the background thread.
3. The background thread sends messages to the Handler with each update.
4. The Handler gets called and makes the necessary changes on the Activity's thread.

No globally shared variables, no potential read/write errors, everyone goes home happy.

Comment: Thanks @Femi. But in step 4 above how/when does the Handler get called and make necessary changes on the _Activitys_ _thread_? In step 3 the background thread sends messages to the Handler with each _update_ - I can do this part as I already have the background thread working. But in step 4 I don't have a mechanism in the _Activitys_ _thread_ to poll or listen for updates to the Handler. Can I make the Handler generate an _event_ to Activity's thread? Or when the background thread sends messages to update the Handler, I should design it to also make necessary changes on the Activity's thread?

Comment: The Android platform's Handler implementation takes care of that: as long as you implement step 1 above, your Handler's `handleMessage` method will be called with any Messages you send on the Activity's thread. You put the logic to change your Activity in the `handleMessage` method.

Comment: Thanks again @Femi. Now I understand to put my logic to change my Activity in the handleMessage method. But how will handleMessage have access to my Activity's classes, methods, etc. Should I expose static methods for my Handler? Also should I start a new question since you have answered the most important part (use a Handler) of this question?

Comment: No need to start a new question: `handleMessage` will have access to all your Activity's methods and variables. I personally always define my Handlers using the following syntax: `private Handler msgHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {}};` and then you can call any methods you like. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Femi. How does handleMessage have access to **all** my Activity's methods and variables unless they are **all** declared static or something? Instead I created one new method: public static void processData(Message msg) { String strData = (String) msg.obj; } and strData is corrupted.

Comment: `handleMessage`'s access is part of the Java language contract: if you declare it as I showed it is considered an inner class and it has access to all class variables. Do not use a static method: you can just use a regular instance method. All Handler `handleMessage` calls occur on the Activity's main thread: the Android platform takes care of that. Once you are in `handleMessage` you can pass the data directly to the plotting activity: no one else is accessing that String variable, so you shouldn't have any corruption.

Comment: @Femi I want to understand this. Maybe I am not creating the handler and passing it to the background thread correctly. What I know is my Bluetooth Activity's main class has an append() method that gets called every time new data is coming in from my Bluetooth device. Below this append() method I created the Handler and call it's handleMessage() from the append() method. Inside my Plotting Activity's main class I created a non-static method: public void processData(Message msg) {} and I am now calling it as a regular instance method from within handleMessage().

Comment: @Femi Using logcat I have discovered that processData() is being reentered. The data looks fine, but it's not being passed as one nice string - it's broken up into pieces perhaps due to the reentrant calls to processData(). I did not have this problem using the static variable method shown at the top of this question: BlueSentry.strData = BlueSentry.strData + Character.toString(printableB); But I guess it's best to debug/solve the Handler approach since it is the preferred approach!

Comment: @Vince, the Handler should not be INSIDE the `append()` method, it should be a class variable that is set one time in the class, as shown in the example I linked to above. You would then put the `strData = strData + Character.toString(printableB);` in the `handleMessage` method: `strData` would also be a class variable.

Comment: @Femi I did not put the Handler inside append(). I put the _call_ to _handleMessage()_ inside append(). And yes, Handler is a class variable set one time in the class. But what's the point in making strData a class variable? My append() method receives a byte[] buffer from which it constructs strData a byte at time. When append() is done constructing strData, it passes strData to handleMessage(). Anyway I have changed append() to pass the byte[] buffer directly to handleMessage() rather than waiting for append() to construct strData.

Comment: Ah. You never directly call `handleMessage`. You **send** a Message using `Handler.sendMessageDelayed` because that delivers the message on the right thread. Take a look at http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-developmentthreading-part-1-handlers/ for a much longer, detailed discussion that should answer most of your questions: hard to capture that in a comment.

Comment: @Femi I've looked at mobileorchard.com. In your comment you say "You never directly call handleMessage" - but I DO! So I think what you **really** mean is that I SHOULD NOT do that. Right? Then what do I do? I think I need to understand how to send a message using Handler.sendMessageDelayed() I guess. How do I do that? Who calls that? It's not explicitly mentioned in mobileorchard.com.

Comment: @Femi OK so Handler.sendMessageDelayed() is in fact _mentioned_ in a list for sending messages in a _timely_ _manner_ in mobileorchard.com. But I am not interested in that - I want to send the message **IMMEDIATELY**. So please, what do I call and who calls it? It's hard for me to understand if I am not supposed to call **any** Handler related method from my append() method. Am I wrong in thinking that since the data comes in through my append() method then somehow append() should make an explicit call to a Handler method? If my append() method does make an explicit call then who does and how?

Comment: Yes, you should NOT call `handleMessage` yourself. You should do something like `Message m = Message.obtain(); m.obj = Character.toString(printableB); handler.sendMessageDelayed(m, 1);` in your background thread (you'll have to pass the Handler object to the thread). Then in your `handleMessage` you call `append` with the Message's `obj` field and you can add it to the `strData` variable. The very small delay (1 millisecond above) is generally acceptable timing. Doing it this way ensures that only 1 thread is ever modifying `strData`.

Comment: @Femi I don't know how to "pass the Handler object to the thread." The file I am editing is 3363 lines long and it's primarily a Bluetooth terminal emulator. I don't stand much chance (unless you can tell me) of passing anything to the background thread when I can't tell where it begins or ends. OK, Handler is a class variable set one time in the class. Done. But I missed something when I was supposed to "pass the Handler object to the thread." How? And what sense does it make to call append() when the thread is probably already calling append() when my Bluetooth device has data.

Comment: Ah. Well, first, create a Handler class variable in the 3363-line file you are editing. Then modify the constructor of that class to take in a Handler variable. Then when you create a new instance of the Bluetooth terminal emulator in the Activity class add the Handler instance to the constructor arguments. Then in the Bluetooth terminal emulator use the `sendMessageDelayed` call we discussed above on the Handler instance you now have. That should cover it.

Comment: Femi, submitted comment by mistake. Please ignore.

Comment: @Femi, my huge file (BlueSentry.java 3363 lines) contains 8 classes! In the class that contains append() there is _already_ a Handler() called mHandler with handlerMessage() that calls update() with no parameters. But inside update() there is a call to append(byte[] buffer, int base, int length). So inside update() I put a call to a regular instance method in my plotting activity. So now I am back to where I was before with data broken into pieces, but I think that is to be expected since the terminal emulator prints the data as it gets it a few characters at a time from my Bluetooth device.

Comment: @Femi, I want to thank you for all your hard. How can I cast votes for you? You saved me from a simple but problematic static variable solution, and you got me started using Handlers. There is much more I have to learn. I cannot find where mHandler (already existing) is being passed into a constructor. But there is a Runnable containing a run() method that calls mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000) which confuses me. I don't know how it works with 1000. I will keep looking: 3400 lines and 8 classes in one file is hard for me to comprehend. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Femi this has got to be the longest most detailed answer to a question I have ever seen. Thanks again! My question(s) continue to evolve as I learn more.